# Dockerfile CMD instruction will exit the container just after running it

Tags: bash, shell, docker, sh, dockerfile

I want to setup some configuration when my container starts, for this I am using shell scripts. But my container will exits as soon as my scripts ends, I have tried with -d flag / detached mode but It will never run in detached mode.

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ADD shell.sh /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

CMD /usr/local/bin/shell.sh
```

Below is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello-docker
```

1. Run without any flag

   ```
   docker run hello-docker
   ```

   This will print 'Hello-docker' on my console and exits
2. Run with -itd flags

   ```
   docker run -itd hello-docker
   ```

   and as below my console output, This time also will exits soon.  **:(**
   [image]

   - The difference I saw is in COMMAND section when I run other images command section will shows "/bin/bash" and will continue in detached mode.
   - And when I run my image in container with shell script COMMAND section will show "/bin/sh -c /usr/loca", and Exit.
   - I want to run container till I not stop it manually.

EDIT:

After adding ENTRYPOINT instruction in Dockerfile, this will not execute my shell script :(

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ADD shell.sh /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

CMD /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

As per docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)

CMD will be overridden when running the container with alternative arguments, so If I run docker image with some arguments as below, will not execute CMD instructions. :(

```
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash <imagename>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Finally with some experiments I got my best result as below

There is nothing wrong with my Dockerfile as below it's correct.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ADD shell.sh /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/shell.sh

CMD /usr/local/bin/shell.sh
```

What I do to get expected result is, I just add one more command(/bin/bash) in my shell script file as below and vola everything works in my best way.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo “Hello-docker” > /usr/hello.txt

/bin/bash
```

Comment: To just do it in the dockerfile itself: `RUN /bin/echo -e "#!/bin/bash\npython welcome.py\n/bin/bash" > /usr/local/bin/onstartup.sh && chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/onstartup.sh` then `CMD /usr/local/bin/onstartup.sh`

Comment: Thanks Anand, this works for me. In my case: ```# Create an executable file that starts the server... 
# A unix executable .sh-file must start with #!/bin/bash. '\n' means 'newline'.
RUN printf '#!/bin/bash\n/etc/NX/nxserver --startup\n/bin/bash'"" > /etc/NX/nxserverStart.sh
# .. and make it actually executable ...
RUN chmod +x /etc/NX/nxserverStart.sh
# Start the nomachine-remote server when the container runs, and ...
CMD ["/etc/NX/nxserverStart.sh"]``` and running the container with ```docker run -d -t -p 4000:4000 --name 'linux_remote_pc' 'linux_remote_pc_image' ```

Comment: OH my God, You did it simply. Best answer!

Answer (score 48):

A docker container will run as long as the `CMD` from your Dockerfile takes.

In your case your `CMD` consists of a shell script containing a single echo. So the container will exit after completing the echo.

You can override `CMD`, for example:

```
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash <imagename>
```

This will start an interactive shell in your container instead of executing your `CMD`. Your container will exit as soon as you exit that shell.

If you want your container to remain active, you have to ensure that your `CMD` keeps running. For instance, by adding the line `while true; do sleep 1; done` to your shell.sh file, your container will print your hello message and then do nothing any more until you stop it (using docker stop in another terminal).

You can open a shell in the running container using `docker exec -it <containername> bash`. If you then execute command `ps ax`, it will show you that your shell.sh is still running inside the container.

Comment: But this will not execute CMD instruction, my shell script will not getting executed. :(

Comment: That is correct. You can't have both. the only other option is to keep your `CMD` running. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: But I want to execute my script too, and I don't want to execute it manually. That's the problem.

Answer (score 25):

You can also modify your first Dockerfile, replacing

`CMD /usr/local/bin/shell.sh`

by

`CMD /usr/local/bin/shell.sh ; sleep infinity`

That way, your script does not terminate, and your container stays running.

Comment: This will work, but after this If I attach with container and want to inspect some thing it will not respond. Like If execute ls -l command nothing will happen.

Comment: Instead of attach, you can `docker exec container_id__or_name ls -l`

Comment: But still I am feeling there is a more batter way to this instead of using ; sleep infinity.

Comment: you can also do something in your CMD like `bash -C '/path/to/start.sh';'bash'` that way,when your script completes, you have a shell, see http://www.markbetz.net/2014/03/17/docker-run-startup-scripts-then-exit-to-a-shell/

Answer (score 6):

```
CMD bash -C '/path/to/start.sh';'bash'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
CMD /bin/bash -c 'MY_COMMAND_OR_SHELL_SCRIPT; /bin/bash'
```

Trying an explanation here to the answer of @lanni654321. `sh` shell is standard in Dockerfile. You must call `bash` shell to start `bash` with `.bashrc`, many commands also need `RUN /bin/bash -c '...'` in the same way as in `CMD` above, since `sh` shell is often not enough. If you add 'bash' in the end of `CMD`, the container will not exit because the image was committed with something that is still open.

See [“/bin/sh: 1: MY_COMMAND: not found”](https://superuser.com/questions/1634933/bin-sh-1-my-command-not-found) for an error caused by `sh` and solved by `bash`.

I think that you will usually not need this. You can just use `RUN /bin/bash -c '...'`, in my case, this could do anything that can be done in a base image before you go into varying details in `docker-compose` to start the containers.

But that is all not needed if you need to just have a container running without exiting. Just

```
docker run -dit --name MY_CONTAINER MY_IMAGE:latest
```

and then

```
docker exec -it MY_CONTAINER /bin/bash
```

and you should be in the bash of the container, and it should not exit.

Or if the exit happens during `docker-compose`, use

```
command: bash -c "MY_COMMAND --wait"
```

Answer (score 3):

At your start shell append a line code:
`tail -f /dev/null` or `/bin/bash`
to make sure you shell done and suspend a process in system so that docker container not shutdown.Don't forget to give "chmod +x" access to start.sh.
there is demo:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /root/supervisor/${RUN_SERVICE}.ini /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
sleep 1
service supervisor start
/bin/bash
```