# Docker container not getting up

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

MAINTAINER rlabs

LABEL Remarks="This is a dockerfile example for Centos system"

# Install Java
RUN yum update -y \
&& yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y \
&& yum clean all \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/yum \
&& yum -y install httpd httpd-tools

# Install Python
RUN yum install python3 -y \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
&& if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi \
&& if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi \
&& yum clean all \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/yum
# load generic RPMs
RUN pip3 install boto3 \
 && yum -y install sudo \
 && yum -y install git \
 && yum -y install gem \
 && yum -y install wget \
 && yum -y install gcc

RUN yum -y install unzip \
 && yum -y install net-tools \
 && yum -y install tcpdump

# add local files to image
COPY aws/aws_config_template /root/.aws/config
COPY aws/aws_credentials_template /root/.aws/credentials

RUN useradd myuser
RUN ln -s /root/.aws /home/myuser


COPY mydir /site/mydir
RUN mkdir /site/log

COPY systemctl.py /usr/bin/systemctl
RUN chmod a+x /usr/bin/systemctl

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8001

RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /site
USER myuser
WORKDIR /site/mydir
```

When I add this in Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT["ping"]
CMD["google.com]
```

and then run command:

```
docker run -d -p 8001:8001 myimage
```

Docker container runs fine. I am able to ssh into my container and run one shell script which runs the jar file and expose the 8001 port.

But if I try to run same shell script by adding CMD like this in Dockerfile
`CMD["sh","/site/mydire/myfile.sh"]`
and remove ENTRYPOINT from the Dockerfile and then run command:

```
docker run -d -p 8001:8001 myimage
```

nothing happens. On doing docker ps, container spins up for a second or two and then gets deleted automatically.If i do docker ps again, nothing shows up.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: FYI, you are missing the closing `"` in `CMD["/site/mydire/myfile.sh]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile CMD instruction will exit the container just after running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218957/dockerfile-cmd-instruction-will-exit-the-container-just-after-running-it)

Comment: Same issue: 
'''$ docker run -p 8001:8001 myimage

server starting...

server started
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES'''