# Jenkins can't find a cloud agent

Tags: jenkins

ive condensed the problem down into 1 image

[image: evidence of whats happening]

theres no space in the name, or any typo like that.

weirdly though it does auto complete, like it kind of knows docker-agent-python is there.

what might be causing this?

what other info would be helpful to provide?

#### ps

im following everything this tutorial does and im around 45 minutes in.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YZvp2GwT0A

#### extra evidence to see if that helps

[image: extra evidence]

Comment: What happens if you save anyway and just try running the job? Jenkins sometimes gives false positives like this.

Comment: it just hangs, claiming it cant find anything by that label

Comment: ive added extra evidence to show that

Comment: Use Provision via option under your nodes(Jenkins-url/manage/computer/) to check is agent coming online or not. check launch logs also then it will help to narrow down issue

Answer (score 2):

The "[Using Jenkins agents3](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/)" documentation illustrates how to create anew node (cloud):

[image: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/resources/node/node-2.png]

In `Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Nodes`, do check you see it listed:

[image: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/resources/node/node-3.png]

> You should now see `This node is being launched.`.
> If that’s not the case, you can now press the `Relaunch agent` button and wait a few seconds. You can now click on the `Log` button on the left, then you should receive the message:
>
> ```
> Agent successfully connected and online on the last log line.
> ```
>
> [image: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/resources/node/node-4.png]
>
> If your Jenkins controller does not start the agent via ssh, please check the port you [configured](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/#ssh-anchor) on your agent. Copy it, and then click on the `Advanced…​` button. You will then be able to paste the port number into the `Port` textfield.

So double-check and try to follow that process, and see if the agent would be available then in your Job definition.

---

Note: the [comments from your video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YZvp2GwT0A&lc=Ugz7ziXxW-0jR8u9dDN4AaABAg.9hYiUNggkye9qEeEIpkIjH) suggests an issue with the image used:

> I wasn't able to get jenkins to install python so I couldn't finish the last 2 projects
>
> Same issue but it was the agent, docker agent python, it was messed but ima do another.

The tutorial attempts to replace docker-agent-alpine (in which python3 is not known) by docker-agent-python, [which you can see here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/devopsjourney1/myjenkinsagents/python/images/sha256-b8aa6f53acd4ee8a304fcc93f6a667d5acda02df977647f2cd5e15e3854d7941?context=explore).
It has a `CMD ["/bin/sh"]`: as explained in "[Dockerfile `CMD` instruction will exit the container just after running it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66737923/6309)", try and run it to check its log and see if it is because of that CMD it exits immediately.

For example, [`jenkins/jnlp-agent-python`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkins/jnlp-agent-python/latest/images/sha256-5c41dcd278717ced7c4e3beb8c30378ca32607c4846159f86c2a24c2232b8aa2?context=explore) uses an `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jenkins-agent"]` which seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IP used in jenkins and IP which is being used by docker.
I also has the same issue after changing IP it worked, seems like docker IP is changing after restart .